# Django Q lookup returning duplicates which are found in both models

Tags: django, django-queryset

In below queryset I have used or condition but still it is returning me the duplicates.

```
queryset = queryset.filter(reduce(or_, [
                Q(user__skill__title__contains=q) |
                Q(user__availability__locations__contains=q) for q in ['Python', 'Perl', 'C++', 'Unix']
                ]))
```

Please advice.

Comment: I tried using .distinct() at the end and it worked however not sure if it is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use distinct on queryset `queryset.distinct()`